# Using powershell and psexec

Tags: powershell, psexec

I'm trying the following script by witch I want to do the following:

1. Get the computers contained in an AD group
2. Run 3 commands with `psexec` for each member

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]

$adgroup   = "GROUP"
$property  = "Name"
$aduser    = "DOMAIN\USER"
$aduserpw  = "PASSWORD"
$commands  = @("klist -li 0x3e7 purge", "gpupdate /force", "wuauclt /detectnow /updatenow")
$workdir   = "c:\windows\system32"
$computers = Get-ADGroupMember $adgroup | Select-Object -Property $property |
             Sort-Object

Set-Alias psexec "D:\SysInternalsSuite\PsExec.exe"

$computers | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($c in $commands) {
         $client = $_ | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String 
         & psexec /acceptEula \\$client /u $aduser /p $aduserpw -w $workdir $c
    }
}
```

But it won't work... I get the following output:

```
PsExec.exe : 
At line:21 char:10
+          & psexec /acceptEula \\$client /u $aduser /p $aduserpw -w $w ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
The handle is invalid.
Connecting to 
COMPUTERNAME
...Couldn't access 
COMPUTERNAME
:
Connecting to 
COMPUTERNAME
...
```

Comment: Are you running this in powershell.exe or PowerShell ISE?

Comment: If you are assigning a variable never pipe to `Format-Table`, or any of the `Format-` cmdlets. Change the `$Computers = ` line so that it reads `$Computers = Get-ADGroupMember $adgroup | Select -Expand Name | Sort` and then maybe do `ForEach($Client in $Computers){` instead of `$Computers | ForEach-Object{` and remove the `$Client = ` line entirely.

Comment: Thank you @ThaMadTechnician !!! It worked!!!